# Fiona accessing coordinates of multiple polygons in a shapefile

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I am working on a shapefile that contains 4 polygons where I need to extract their coordinates in a tuple or numpy array for later manipulation. While fiona identifies the 4 polygons, using shapely to get the area only gives me the value for the first polygon.

I would like to pick the xy coordinate for all polygons and put them separately into arrays and tuples for processing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import fiona
import pprint
from shapely.geometry import shape, Polygon

c = fiona.open("myShapeFile.shp", 'r')
pprint.pprint(len(c))
poly = Polygon(next(iter(c))["geometry"]["coordinates"][:])
print('Area  :: ',poly.area)
```

The execution gives me the following:

4

Area     ::  483.6379565269977

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but does building the polygon like this help? `Polygon([p['geometry']['coordinates'] for p in c])`

Comment: Hi Milan. thanks for your comment, but using your the loop as you suggest gives me an error. I am expecting the code above to give me 4 areas for the contained polygons in the shapefile. What I get now is the afrea of the first polygon. I don't know how to access the coordinates in an array too.

Comment: Can you share the shapefile?

Comment: You also need to upload the .shx file, otherwise `fiona.open` fails.

Comment: The shapefile you shared contains only one feature (i.e. len(c) == 1). However, you can iterate through the c object as you would a dict: `for k, v in c.iteritems()` and build polygons in the body of the loop: `poly = Polygon(v['geometry']['coordinates'])`. HTH

Comment: Here I put the shapefiles with 4 features: an outer polygon with 3 gaps inside: shapefile shp: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbzgxzke9q4fqfu/myShapefile.shp?dl=0           shx: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7lrlswsnzwjnqu/myShapefile.shx?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import fiona
import numpy as np

c = fiona.open('myShapeFile.shp')
coords = [np.array(poly['geometry']['coordinates'])
          for poly in c.values()]
```

`coords` is a 4 item list holding numpy arrays built from the coordinates of the polygons from the shapefile:

```
[array([[ 3.67739738e+05,  6.35697708e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.67709140e+05,  6.35875947e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.55633222e+05,  6.35932405e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.55340980e+05,  6.35724482e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.54012992e+05,  6.35713924e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.53169984e+05,  6.33306237e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.72936914e+05,  6.33219322e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.73638262e+05,  6.34799928e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.70536492e+05,  6.34865912e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.71030683e+05,  6.35672004e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.67739738e+05,  6.35697708e+06, -1.50000000e+03]]),
 array([[ 3.60619254e+05,  6.35486104e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.61702258e+05,  6.35460318e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.62578977e+05,  6.35362332e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.61805402e+05,  6.35192145e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.60412965e+05,  6.35114787e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.59072102e+05,  6.35171516e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.59020527e+05,  6.35279817e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.60309824e+05,  6.35295288e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.60000391e+05,  6.35408746e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.60619254e+05,  6.35486104e+06, -1.50000000e+03]]),
 array([[ 3.59072102e+05,  6.34439198e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.60928684e+05,  6.34537184e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.62424262e+05,  6.34480455e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.63868270e+05,  6.34361841e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.63146266e+05,  6.34155554e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.61341258e+05,  6.34036939e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.60258250e+05,  6.34109139e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.61650688e+05,  6.34227754e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.61289688e+05,  6.34356684e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.59897250e+05,  6.34294798e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.57989094e+05,  6.34346370e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.59072102e+05,  6.34439198e+06, -1.50000000e+03]]),
 array([[ 3.69489590e+05,  6.34294798e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.71397742e+05,  6.34103982e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.69438016e+05,  6.33928638e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.67581438e+05,  6.34052411e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.67787723e+05,  6.34222597e+06, -1.50000000e+03],
       [ 3.69489590e+05,  6.34294798e+06, -1.50000000e+03]])]
```